# transfer data from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, export

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that contains all my data that I need to put into an SQL Server database. I am fairly new o ASP.NET and have never had to export from Excel to SQL Server before.

My Excel spreadsheets looks like this

> Trade Heading -> ArtID -> BusinessName -> AdStyleCode -> Address -> Suburb

In SQL Server I have created a table named "Listings" which is in this format

> intListingID -> intCategoryID -> BusinessName - ArtID -> intAdCode ->Address -> Suburb

What would be the best way to export the data from Excel and then import it into SQLServer 2005.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily using SSIS, you can refer to these two links for full details.

1. [Link 1](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/How-to-import-an-Excel-file-into-SQL-Server-2005-using-Integration-Services/0,339028455,339285948,00.htm)
2. [Link 2](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=205)

[EDIT]

If you have Express then you can try the below commands to setup a linked server and get the data

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver ExcelData,'Jet 4.0','Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','C:\MyData.xls', NULL, 'Excel 5.0;'
GO
```

Then you can select the data into your tables

```
INSERT INTO Listings ...
SELECT column1 AS intListingID, <put all columns here> FROM ExcelData...Data
GO
```

For other options check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/euanga/archive/2006/07/20/672272.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much Binoj for the link. Hopefully this will solve my issue.

Comment: Also after reading these posts. Do I need the full version of SQL Server to achive this. I only have SQL Server Express

Comment: Link1 and Link2 are redirected to the home pages of the associated websites now. Might have to link to the pages in archive.org.

Comment: Link1 and Link2 still broken links.

Answer (score 0):

I tried exporting data from Excel to SQL server through VBA like this:

```
Const myDB As String = "tenant"
Const myServer As String = "MPAADM"
Const myDB As String = "new"
Const myServer As String = "arjun"

Sub ExportTableToSQL()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngRecsAff As Long
    Dim sqlTable As String
    Dim acell As Range
    Dim t1 As Date
    Dim t2 As Date
    Dim column As String

    On Error Resume Next
    path = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value

    Kill path & \z_temp\aa.xls"
    Kill path & "\z_temp\aa.xls"

    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo 10
    column = Cells(1, 1).Value

        sqlTable = InputBox("Insert SQL table name")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    t1 = Now
    Debug.Print t1
    If sqlTable = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set acell = ActiveCell
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        MsgBox "Select a cell inside a table you want to export to SQL"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Call NewWorkbook
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnSQL
        .ConnectionString = "provider=sqloledb;Data Source=" & myServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & myDB & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
        '      .ConnectionString = "provider=sqloledb;Data Source=" & myServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & myDB & ";Uid=jayantuser;Pwd=Input@123"
        .Open
    End With


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "\z_temp\aa.xls"

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & path & "\z_temp\aa.xls;" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"


    strSQL = "drop table " & sqlTable
    Debug.Print strSQL
    On Error Resume Next
    cnSQL.Execute strSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 10

    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};" & _
        "Server=" & myServer & ";Database=" & myDB & _
        ";trusted_connection=yes]." & sqlTable & _
        " FROM [sheet1$]"

Debug.Print strSQL    
    cn.Execute strSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords    
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill path & "\z_temp\aa.xlx"
    On Error GoTo 0
    t2 = Now
    Debug.Print t2
    MsgBox sqlTable & " table was successfully imported into SQL Server" & vbNewLine & "Transfered record number: " & lngRecsAff _
    & vbNewLine & "Time:" & Int((t2 - t1) * 86400) & "s"
    If MsgBox("Convert data type to bigint?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        strSQL = "ALTER TABLE " & sqlTable & " ALTER COLUMN " & column & " bigint"
        cnSQL.Execute strSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords
    End If 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    acell.Select
    Exit Sub
10: MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub                                                                       `Sub NewWorkbook()
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Workbooks.Add
End Sub`                                                                     
   `Sub Quit()
    Application.Quit
End Sub`
```