# sql linking to excel

Tags: sql, excel-2007

I need to Link sql to Excel: when I write select in Sql, I want to write result automatically into excel.
Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here :  [Excel -> SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720654/transfer-data-from-excel-to-sql-server)

You need to look at the Microsoft's website :

- [Excel with Database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397)

More information : [Connect SQL Sever with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123624/can-you-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel)

---

In case you require the reverse-way round, please visit the following link :

- [Excel to SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Excel2Sql.aspx)